# How to know if an audio file being played has finished in PhoneGap (Cordova)?

Tags: javascript, cordova

How can I know if the audio file has been finished playing completely and not stopped by user?
I see that [Media](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media)'s callback `mediaStatus` is reported by one of the following states:

```
Media.MEDIA_NONE = 0;
Media.MEDIA_STARTING = 1;
Media.MEDIA_RUNNING = 2;
Media.MEDIA_PAUSED = 3;
Media.MEDIA_STOPPED = 4;
```

I'm using PhoneGap version 2.5. So is it possible?

Comment: i have same question...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mediaStatus with code "4" is called only when playing was stopped playing because of end of file. I.e. when I call "media.stop()" mediaStatus is not called. At least, it works so on my device, when I call "media.stop()" inside "mediaStatus"

Anyway, you can settle variable like "wasStoppedIntentionallyInCode" and set it to true when you stop playing from code. In this case in mediaStatus you'll be able to make difference: was playing stopped by code or file was just played to the end.